# Can 1 Recordset execute 2 Select queries at the same time?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have 2 functions that I use throughout my database. I was wondering if I can 'merge' the two to "shorten" up my code.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim strTaxR As String
Dim strYTDG As String

Public Function fncTRate(ByVal PEnd As Date) As Double

strTaxR = "SELECT TOP 1 [Tax Rate] As TRate FROM tblTax WHERE [Effective Date] <= #" & PEnd & "#" ORDER BY [Effective Date] DESC;"

    With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strTaxR)
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            fncTRate = .Fields("TRate")
        End If
    End With

End Function

Public Function fncYTDG(EmpN As Integer, PEnd As Date) As Double

strYTDG = "SELECT Sum([SGROSS]) As YTDG FROM qryYTD2 WHERE [PE] Between #" & DateSerial(Year(PEnd ), 1, "1") & "# And #" & PEnd & "# And [EID]=" & EmpN

    With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strYTDG)
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            fncYTDG = .Fields("YTDG")
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Will compacting it make a difference or should I leave it as is?

Comment: As shown, functions cannot be merged as each returns a value to wherever it is called from.

Comment: Regarding question title - a recordset is based on a SELECT query and only one. So basically the answer is no to question as worded.

Comment: Having separate functions is the way to go! don't complicate it :)

Comment: Much thanks to everyone for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```vb
Public Function fncGrossRate( _
    ByVal GrossOrRate As Integer, _
    ByVal PEnd As Date, _
    Optional ByVal EmpN As Integer) _
    As Currency

    Dim SQL     As String
    Dim Result  As Currency

    Select Case GrossOrRate
        Case 0
            SQL = "SELECT TOP 1 [Tax Rate] As TRate FROM tblTax " & _
                "WHERE [Effective Date] <= #" & Format(PEnd, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# ORDER BY [Effective Date] DESC;"
        Case 1
            SQL = "SELECT Sum([SGROSS]) As YTDG FROM qryYTD2 " & _
                "WHERE [PE] Between #" & Format(DateSerial(Year(PEnd), 1, 1), "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format(PEnd, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And [EID]=" & EmpN & ""
    End Select

    If SQL <> "" Then
        With CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
            If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
                Result = .Fields(0).Value
            End If
        End With
    End If

    fncGrossRate = Result

End Function
```

But, as already stated by *June*, the direct answer to your question is *No*.